# How to express some coefficient of a generating function using only its derivatives

Tags: partial-differential-equations, generating-functions, nonlinear-dynamics

I have a series of terms, $a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{k-1}$ that depend on $t$. I describe them in the form of the generating function, $Q(x,t)=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}a_{i}(t)x^{i}$. My goal is to end up with a partial differential equation in $Q,Q_{t},Q_{x},x$, where subscripts indicate partial derivatives.
My problem is that in calculating $Q_{t}$, I end up with terms in $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$. For those interested, the equation I get is
$$\begin{align}
Q_{t}+\left(x-\frac{1+p}{2}\right)Q_{x}= \ &\frac{1-p}{2}(x+x^{k-1})(Q_{x}|_{1})\\
&-\left(\frac{1+p}{2}+\frac{1-p}{2}x+px^{k-1}\right)a_{1}\\
&+2pa_{2},
\end{align}$$
where $Q_{x}|_{1}$ is the partial $x$ derivative of $Q$ at $x=1$, and $p$ is a constant.
With that in mind, could someone please explain to me how to express $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$ in terms of $Q$ and its $x$ derivatives, if it is even possible? EDIT: Answered in comments

Comment: What about $a_1$ is equal to $Q_x$ evaluated at $x=0$, and $a_2$ is equal to $\frac{1}{2}Q_{xx}$ at $x=0$?

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. The n^th coefficient is the n^th derivative over n! at 0, duh. Exponential functions, Yaniv, gawd, you know this.